# β is a basis for V iff T(β) is a basis for the range R(T)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let **V**,**W** be vector spaces over the same field **F**, and β be a subset of **V**.
Suppose T: **V** → **W** is linear and one-to-one.
Show that β is a basis for V if and only if T(β) is a basis for the range R(T)

my pf) ($\Rightarrow$)

WTS: T($\beta$) is a basis for the range R(T) if $\beta$ is a basis for **V**

Let β := {$v_1, $$v_2$$, $$\dots$$, $$v_n$}
Then, $\exists$$v$ $\in$ **V** such that $v$ = $a_1$$v_1$ + $\dots$ + $a_n$$v_n$
for each $a_1$, $\dots$ , $a_n$ $\in$ **F**

$\Rightarrow$$v$= $\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$

$\Rightarrow$T($v$)=T( $\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i$) = $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$T($v_i$) $\in$ span(T($\beta$))

$\Rightarrow$R(T) $\subseteq$ span(T($\beta$))

Conversley, we can find span(T($\beta$))$\subseteq$R(T)

So, R(T)=span(T($\beta$))

now I am going to prove span(T($\beta$)) is linearly independent.

But I have no idea to this and proof of $\Leftarrow$ direction

pleas give me some hints.

Comment: The mapping $T:V\to R(T)$ is an isomorphism. The inverse mapping $T^{-1}:R(T)\to V$ is a linear bijection and $T^{-1}[T(\beta)]=\beta.$ If $T(\beta)$ is a basis in $R(T)$ so is $\beta$ in $V.$

Comment: I know one to one $\iff$ onto so bijection. However, Isomorphism $\iff$ dim (V) = dim (R(T)). How does it prove dim(V) = dim (R(T))?

Comment: For linear maps bijection and isomorphism is  the same thing.

Comment: I got it! and how to prove T($\beta$) is linearly independent?

Comment: You did give a proof in your post.

Comment: Well... I proved span(T($\beta$)) = R(T), you mean it gives me T($\beta$) is a basis for R(T)? I cannot be sure to T($v_1$),T($v_2$), $\dots$, T($v_n$) are linearly independent.

Comment: They are as $T$ is one to one.